# Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to **retrieve values** from Firebase and **calculate the means of those values** by looping the sum of every path in Firebase and keep in each variable.

Then, I divide by the **number of checkCount**.

But it shows me an error like this...

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "…  A 50 50 0 0 1 NaN
>   NaN".

I found that this error come from the > `Summand` values

> this.total1 = (**this.total1** / this.checkedCount) //Line 35 - 42

How can I solve this? :((

```
total1: number = 0
total2: number = 0
total3: number = 0
total4: number = 0
total5: number = 0
total6: number = 0
total7: number = 0
total8: number = 0
checkedCount: number = 0

calculateProfile() {

this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(data => {
  if (data && data.email && data.uid) {

    var userRef = firebase.database().ref('/profile').child(data.uid)

    for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) { // Loop all the 1st paths in Firebase
      for (let j = 1; j < 5; j++) { // Loop all the 2nd paths in Firebase
        userRef.child('/unit').child('' + (i)).child('/lesson').child('' + (j))
          .on('value', snap => {

              ++this.checkedCount //count every path for division 
              this.total1 += snap.val().count1
              this.total2 += snap.val().count2
              this.total3 += snap.val().count3
              this.total4 += snap.val().count4
              this.total5 += snap.val().count5
              this.total6 += snap.val().count6
              this.total7 += snap.val().count7
              this.total8 += snap.val().count8
            }//End if
          })//End on
      }
    }
    this.total1 = (this.total1 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total2 = (this.total2 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total3 = (this.total3 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total4 = (this.total4 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total5 = (this.total5 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total6 = (this.total6 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total7 = (this.total7 / this.checkedCount)
    this.total8 = (this.total8 / this.checkedCount)
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved yesterday..

It might be the problem of using the same variable.

So, I declare variables for keeping those divided data.
I gonna close this. :D